# Is it possible to highlight a specific segment in a Google Gantt Chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization, gantt-chart

I am attempting to make a Gantt chart using the [Google Charts library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart). The library gives the ability to indicate the percentage of a task's completion, but I am not interested in that feature. Instead, I am interested in highlighting the part of the task that is overdue. Say, a task was due by the 4th of this month, but it is currently the 8th and the task is still not finished. I would like to highlight the area that represents the overdue period.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: not out of the box, you would need to manually change the color of the chart element, once the chart's `'ready'` event fires.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.